# How does adding a break in a while loop resolve overload ambiguity?

Tags: c#

Consider this Reactive Extensions snippet (ignore the practicality of it):

```
return Observable.Create<string>(async observable =>
{
    while (true)
    {
    }
});
```

This does not compile with Reactive Extensions 2.2.5 (using NuGet Rx-Main package). It fails with:

> Error  1   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Create<string>(System.Func<System.IObserver<string>,System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Action>>)' and 'System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Create<string>(System.Func<System.IObserver<string>,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)'

However, adding a `break` anywhere in the while loop fixes the compilation error:

```
return Observable.Create<string>(async observable =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        break;
    }
});
```

The problem can be reproduced without Reactive Extensions at all (easier if you want to try it without fiddling with Rx):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Observable.Create<string>(async blah =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("foo.");
                break; //Remove this and the compiler will break
            }
        });
    }
}

public class Observable
{
    public static IObservable<TResult> Create<TResult>(Func<IObserver<TResult>, Task> subscribeAsync)
    {
        throw new Exception("Impl not important.");
    }

    public static IObservable<TResult> Create<TResult>(Func<IObserver<TResult>, Task<Action>> subscribeAsync)
    {
        throw new Exception("Impl not important.");
    }
}

public interface IObserver<T>
{
}
```

Ignoring the Reactive Extensions part of it, Why does adding `break` help the C# compiler resolve the ambiguity? How can this be described with the rules of overload resolution from the C# specification?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 targeting 4.5.1.

Comment: @Mic1780: since when do compilers fail when detecting an infinite loop? Never seen that before …

Comment: @Mic1780 No idea what you're talking about. The C# compiler (actually, most compilers) will happily compile an infinite loop, even one as simple as `while(true) {}`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's easiest to just pull out `async` as well as the lambdas here, as it emphasizes what's going on.  Both of these methods are valid and will compile:

```
public static void Foo()
{
    while (true) { }
}
public static Action Foo()
{
    while (true) { }
}
```

However, for these two methods:

```
public static void Foo()
{
    while (true) { break; }
}
public static Action Foo()
{
    while (true) { break; }
}
```

The first compiles, and the second does not.  It has a code path that doesn't return a valid value.

In fact, `while(true){}` (along with `throw new Exception();`) is an interesting statement in that it is the valid body of a method with any return type.

Since the infinite loop is a suitable candidate for both overloads, and neither overload is "better", it results in an ambiguity error.  The non-infinite loop implementation only has one suitable candidate in overload resolution, so it compiles.

Of course, to bring `async` back into play, it is actually relevant in one way here.  For the `async` methods they both always return *something*, whether it's a `Task` or a `Task<T>`.  The "betterness" algorithms for overload resolution will prefer delegates that return a value over `void` delegates when there is a lambda that could match either, however in your case the two overload both have delegates that return a value, the fact that for `async` methods returning a `Task` instead of a `Task<T>` is the conceptual equivalent of not returning a value isn't incorporated into that betterness algorithm.  Because of this the non-async equivalent wouldn't result in an ambiguity error, even though both overloads are applicable.

Of course it's worth noting that writing a program to determine if an arbitrary block of code will ever complete is a famously unsolvable problem, however, while the compiler cannot correctly evaluate whether every single snippet will complete, it can prove, in certain simple cases such as this one, that the code will in fact never complete.  Because of this there are ways of writing code that will clearly (to you and me) never complete, but that the compiler will treat as possibly completing.

Comment: There's something specific to `async` though: given `void Foo(Action a); void Foo(Func f);`, `Foo(() => { throw new Exception(); }); }` is *not* ambiguous and will call the second overload: the language spec favours a delegate with a return type. But `async` functions can have a return type even if they don't actually seem to return a concrete value: it can still have a `Task` return type.

Comment: @hvd Right, added in a paragraph to go over that.

Comment: Interesting. So `while(this.PropertyIsAlwaysTrue) {}` (or `MethodReturnsTrue()`) will again resolve to a method with a fixed return value (because the compiler cannot know that what the property will return).

Comment: @knittl The C# compiler only ever does semantic analysis of a single member block at a time.  It will never look at the source of multiple different methods/properties in order to determine how to compile one of them.  It could, in theory, it's just that doing so gets very hard, very quickly, so the decision was made that it wasn't worth spending that level of effort for what you get in exchange.

Answer (score 25):

Leaving `async` out of this to start with...

With the break, the end of the lambda expression is reachable, therefore the return type of the lambda *has* to be `void`.

Without the break, the end of the lambda expression is unreachable, so *any* return type would be valid. For example, this is fine:

```
Func<string> foo = () => { while(true); };
```

whereas this isn't:

```
Func<string> foo = () => { while(true) { break; } };
```

So without the `break`, the lambda expression would be convertible to any delegate type with a single parameter. With the `break`, the lambda expression is *only* convertible to a delegate type with a single parameter and a return type of `void`.

Add the `async` part and `void` becomes `void` or `Task`, vs `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>` for any `T` where previously you could have any return type. For example:

```
// Valid
Func<Task<string>> foo = async () => { while(true); };
// Invalid (it doesn't actually return a string)
Func<Task<string>> foo = async () => { while(true) { break; } };
// Valid
Func<Task> foo = async () => { while(true) { break; } };
// Valid
Action foo = async () => { while(true) { break; } };
```