# Statements that are valid as body of a function with any return type

Tags: c#

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898541/how-does-adding-a-break-in-a-while-loop-resolve-overload-ambiguity) (or more specifically this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25898647/1552016)) made me wonder: what statements are valid in C# as the body of a function with any return type?

So for example:

```
public void Foo()
{
    while (true) { }
}

public int Foo()
{
    while (true) { }
}
```

Both functions are valid C# functions even though the second one doesn't really return an `int`.

So I know that infinite loops (e.g. `for(;;)`) and `throw new Exception()` like throw statements are valid as the body of any function, but is there more statements with that property?

---

**Update:**

One more solution came to my mind, an infinite recursion:

```
    public string Foo()
    {
        return Foo();
    }
```

Comment: lemme see if my downvoter magic 8 ball works... *shake shake* Hmmm, says try again.  *shake* Says this isn't a problem you're facing and appears to be a poll question without a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting, one example that isn't really different than your second snippet would be:

```
public static int Foo()
{
    do {}
    while (true);
}
```

But I don't think that really counts as "different".

Also, another example of why `goto` is evil:

```
public static int Foo()
{
    start:
    goto start;
}
```

It's also interesting to note that this does give a compilation error:

```
public static int Foo()
{
    bool b = true;
    while (b) 
    {
    }
}
```

Even though `b` doesn't change. But if you *explicitly* make it constant:

```
public static int Foo()
{
    const bool b = true;
    while (b) 
    {
    }
}
```

It works again.

Comment: Yep, I didn't want to include all possible infinite loops in my question, so I wouldn't count do-while as different, but I didn't thought about the goto solution. +1

Comment: I'm not sure that there would be any examples other than infinite loops (that never return) or exceptions, but I'm very interested to see what other people might come up with. File under "stupid C# tricks"

Comment: goto evil? I like it. (Just to note that goto has some defenders - not interested in getting into a discussion about it.)

Comment: `bool b = true;` could be edited at any point in the debugger, flipped to false and .. boom so presumably its explicitly disallowed. The operation on the const cannot change and is also interpreted as an unconditional branch

Answer (score 2):

Its almost the same as the `goto` example but with a `switch` involved:

```
public int Foo()
{
    switch (false)
    {
         case false:
         goto case false;
    }
}
```

Not sure if this qualifies as a new one.

Interestingly enough, the following won't compile:

```
public static int Foo(bool b)
{
    switch (b)
    {
        case true:
        case false:
            goto case false;
    }
}
```

Evidently the compiler has no "knowledge" that a boolean can only have two possible values. You need to explicitly cover all "possible" outcomes:

```
public static int Foo(bool b)
{
    switch (b)
    {
        case true:
        case false:
        default:
            goto case true;
    }
}
```

Or in its simplest form:

```
public static int Foo(bool b)
{
    switch (b)
    {
        default:
            goto default;
    }
}
```

Yeah...I'm bored at work today.

Answer (score 1):

Non-void & no `return`;

```
public IEnumerable Foo()
{
    yield break;
}
```

Comment: Well technically that returns an empty enumeration which is the return type of the method, you aren't getting away without returning anything. I'm pretty sure infinite loops or exceptions are the only answer to the OP's question. But +1 in avoiding `return` :)